# How to make one entire column unselectable in java?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am doing my java project using netbeans. I want to make entire columns except one column unselectable.The user should be only able to click rows in only in one column. How to do that?

Comment: Need more info! What UI framework are you using? AWT, SWT, Swing? What component?

Comment: usual questions: why? what exactly do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 5):

You can add a ListSelectionListener to the your table. If the current selection is the unselectable column, you can undo the selection. Here's an example:

```
public class MyTable extends JTable(){
    //the column to disable
    //... and the currently selected column
    private int disabled_col = 2, cur_col = 0;

    public MyTable(){
        //Create a column selection listener
        final ListSelectionModel sel = this.getColumnModel().getSelectionModel();
        sel.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener(){
            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                //If the column is disabled, reselect previous column
                if (sel.isSelectedIndex(disabled_col))
                    sel.setSelectionInterval(cur_col,cur_col);
                //Set current selection
                else cur_col = sel_mod1.getMaxSelectionIndex();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This code doesn't handle multiple disabled columns or selections spanning multiple columns. You would have to modify it to handle those cases.

Answer (score 1):

Use `setColumnSelectionAllowed(false);` and set you prefered column to it, should work.
Think i used that one on my recent project with a JTable.

*"Column Selection" controls `columnSelectionAllowed` which has setter method `setColumnSelectionAllowed` and getter method `getColumnSelectionAllowed`. When this bound property is `true` (and the `rowSelectionAllowed` bound property is `false`), the user can select by column.*

From http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Comment: if you aren't sure, you could try it :-)

Comment: This is all or nothing, and doesn't really answer the question. The OP would like to know how to make all but one column non-selectable. Your approach will make *all* columns non-selectable.